# Woocommerce Product Scraping Regular and Sale Price not extracting

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, woocommerce, scrapy

I am creating a data scraper using scrapy. I shell the product url using

```
scrapy shell 'https://royalprint.pk/product/name-print-superhero-sweatshirt-011/'
```

and then run this command

```
In [43]: response.css('span.woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol::text').get()
Out[43]: 'Rs'
```

It only returns the currency symbol.

Here is the source code product image

[image]

Someone please correct me what I did wrong here ?

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its might help.

```
for price in response.css('p.price'):
    print(price.xpath('./del/span/bdi/text()').get())
    print(price.xpath('./ins/span/bdi/text()').get())
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply :) your code work perfect but i get the .csv output as 

price sale
¬†1,670 ¬†1,499

I want to know how to remove these ¬† characters

Answer (score 0):

Nothing wrong really, but you just mistaken the element you need to get. I guess you want to get the price number, in that case you should use something like:

```
span.woocommerce-Price-amount bdi::text
```

as you can see, it's the `bdi` element the one containing the information you want, not the inner span

Answer (score 0):

The ***span*** element you are referencing only contains *Rs* text.

`<span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">Rs</span>`

But the *price* information you want is after the closing tag of the ***span*** element.

The price is included in the ***bdi*** element. since we have other ***bdi*** elements on the webpage so we need to reference the exact one.

`response.xpath("//p[@class='price']//bdi/text()").extract()`